# Integrate data frame from R with Smartsheet

Tags: r, integration, smartsheet-api

I want to add data frame row by row to a specific sheet in Smartsheet.
My data frame fields design is: "Name", "Score", and "Email".
and the sheet name from Smartsheet is "Student Scores" with the same field names from R.

How to integrate the information from the data frame to "Student Scores" in smartsheet using API and Sheet ID.

I tried the following, but doesn't work:

```
# Install and Load Necessary R Packages
if (!require("httr")) install.packages("httr")
if (!require("jsonlite")) install.packages("jsonlite")
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

# Set Up API Credentials
api_key <- Sys.getenv("SMARTSHEET_API_KEY")  # Replace with your API key or use an environment variable

# Function to Fetch Column IDs
get_column_ids <- function(sheet_id, api_key) {
  base_url <- "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/"
  response <- GET(
    url = paste0(base_url, sheet_id),
    add_headers(Authorization = paste0("Bearer ", api_key))
  )
  
  if (status_code(response) != 200) {
    stop("Failed to fetch sheet details. Status Code: ", status_code(response))
  }
  
  sheet_data <- fromJSON(rawToChar(response$content))
  columns <- sheet_data$columns
  column_ids <- setNames(sapply(columns, function(col) col$id), sapply(columns, function(col) col$title))
  
  return(column_ids)
}

# Function to Add Rows to Smartsheet
add_rows_to_smartsheet <- function(df, sheet_id, column_ids, api_key) {
  base_url <- "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/"
  rows_to_add <- lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) {
    list(cells = lapply(names(df), function(column_name) {
      list(columnId = column_ids[column_name], value = df[i, column_name])
    }))
  })
  
  body <- list(rows = rows_to_add)
  response <- POST(
    url = paste0(base_url, sheet_id, "/rows"),
    add_headers(Authorization = paste0("Bearer ", api_key), "Content-Type" = "application/json"),
    body = toJSON(body),
    encode = "json"
  )
  
  return(content(response))
}

# Specify Sheet ID
sheet_id <- "YOUR_SHEET_ID"  # Replace with your actual Sheet ID

# Fetch Column IDs
column_ids <- get_column_ids(sheet_id, api_key)

# Prepare Data Frame
df <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"),
  Scores = c(85, 92, 78),
  Email = c("alice@example.com", "bob@example.com", "charlie@example.com")
)

# Add Rows to Smartsheet
result <- add_rows_to_smartsheet(df, sheet_id, column_ids, api_key)
print(result)
```

When I run the code, the following error show:

```
Error in get_column_ids(sheet_id, api_key) : 
  Failed to fetch sheet details. Status Code: 403
```

Any hint or solution?

Thanks

Comment: "The 403 Forbidden error indicates that the server understands the request but can't provide additional access. This means that the web page you're trying to open in your browser is a resource that you're not allowed to access".  So the problem is not with your code but with your access to `https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/`.  As your api key is (quite rightly) private, there's little  concrete advice to give beyond checking your credentials and that your URL is correct.

Comment: In your line: sheet_id <- "YOUR_SHEET_ID"  # Replace with your actual Sheet ID
Did you actually replace the value with a valid sheet id?

Comment: Hello @BigFinger, yes I did, but still the error is show.